# Remove .dll from fody-costura that i no longer use

Tags: c#, fody-costura

a while back I installed `Install-Package Costura.Fody`How ever, back when I installed it I used 3 .dlls, but now I no longer have use of these .dll as I changed my application around. I did delete my 3 dll's from my bin folder, and I removed them from my references. But when ever I build my project Costura.Fody will still include these .dlls. How can I change this?

Comment: Check your `packages.config` file - maybe the packages are still referenced there.

Comment: They were not, how ever it seems to have fixed it self after a few hours and new builds being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours and new builds being created it seems I have fixed it self.